# What is the minimal number of different symbols in the game "Dobble"?

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

There is a game called "Dobble" (or "Spot It!" in some countries) which implies an interesting problem I couldn't solve. The game consists of some amount of cards $c$, which have $s$ distinguishable symbols on them. For every two cards it is guaranteed that they have exactly one symbol in common. Several other questions have been asked about this game (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240113/what-are-the-mathematical-computational-principles-behind-this-game), but I haven't found my question anywhere. I asked myself:

**Given the total number of cards $c$ and the number of symbols $s$ per card, what is the minimum number of distinguishable symbols one has to use in order to fulfill the abovementioned condition?**

I wrote an algorithm which can answer this question in a reasonable time for $c < 6$ and $s < 6$ in Java, it can be found [here](https://github.com/Simonibo/dobble-generate). I'm basically using brute-force to check all possibilities until I can be sure that I've found the optimal one. I used some if-clauses to bail out as early as possible and not generate useless possibiilities, but nevertheless the algorithm isn't fast enough for bigger numbers. If anyone is interested, I would explain the code in more detail (the comments I made are in German).

Here is a table with the values I got so far (extended table can be found [here](https://github.com/Simonibo/dobble-generate/blob/master/values.xlsx)):

```
+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+
|   | 1 | 2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  <- c
+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |  3 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
| 3 | 3 | 5 |  6 |  6 |  7 |  7 |
| 4 | 4 | 7 |  9 | 10 | 10 | 11 |
| 5 | 5 | 9 | 12 | 14 | 15 | 15 |
+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+
  ^
  |
  s
```

If $m(c, s)$ denotes the minimal number of distinguishable symbols, we can write down some (trivial) things:

- $m(1, s) = s$
- $m(2, s) = 2s - 1$
- $m(c, 1) = 1$
- **$m(c, s) \le c * (s - 1) + 1$**

The last inequality comes from the fact that one can always create the following configuration to meat the criterion:

```
1 1 1 1 ...
2 4 6 8 ...
3 5 7 9 ...
```

One column represents one card. This pattern can be applied to any $c$ and $s$ and the amount of different symbols is always $c * (s - 1) + 1$.

Furthermore the columns seem to develop according to $m(c, s + 1) = m(c, s) + c$ for larger $s$ and the rows form according to $m(c + 1, s) = m(c, s) + s - 1$ for larger $c$.

I've also searched the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences for rows and columns of this sequence, but I couldn't find any promising results.

Nevertheless, I have no idea how to develop a formula for such a problem and would be thankful for your help.

Comment: Are you aware that this game is based on finite dimensional projective geometry on vector space $\mathbb{Z_p}^2$ where $p$ is a prime number ? The cards are lines containing points (the symbols). Two lines intersect on a single point, etc. The number of lines is $p^2+p+1$. Dobble game is based on $p=7$ which gives 57 cards (theoreticaly, but may be one of them is not represented). The prime numbers immediately a) before are p=5 and p=3 thus there is a Dobble game with 31 cards (ctd)

Comment: (ctd...) or with 13 cards (not very interesting)  b) on the contrary, if we jump to p=11, there exist a Dobble game with 133 cards... I am not aware of other possibilities in between (with another theory).

Comment: I was forgetting, the number of symbols per card is $p+1$ (so 8 for the usual Dobble game)

Comment: I've read a bit about this, but I don't really understand how this should help answering my question. If I'm misunderstanding something, it would be nice if you could explain it with more detail.

Comment: Maybe we are not on the same wavelength... I have some difficulty to understand for example your last column (with 6 cards) what are the meaning of the figures 1,7,7,11,15... For example, does the figure 7 means "number of symbols by card" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie `p` can be prime or prime power. (and possibly other values, not much is known for bigger composite values).

Comment: @JeanMarie The table shows the values for m(c, s). The headers on the top indicate c and the headers on the left indicate s. The last column shows that for 6 cards with 4 symbols each, you need at least 11 different symbols in total (on all cards). Another example would be that you only need 7 different symbols to fill 6 cards with 2 or 3 symbols each.

Comment: For c<= s we have $m(c,s) = cs - \frac{c(c-1)}{2}$. I think it is also clear that m(s+1,s) = m(s,s) - given a solution with s symbols on s cards, you can add another card without requiring more symbols.. I am struggling to prove anything for the case c > s+1.

Comment: @gandalf61 Great, that's exactly what I've been looking for. The first formula seems obvious when you notice that the diagonal of the table can be computed with the Gaussian sum formula (which I didn't). The second result seems to be clear as well (although again I didn't notice it). If you have s cards with s symbols each, each card has to have at least one symbol which isn't on any other card, and you can always make a new card using these s symbols. Do you have a proof for the first formula?

Answer (score 1):

A theorem of de-Bruijn and Erdos tells us that if I have a universe of $s$ symbols and $c$ cards, and each pair of cards shares exactly one symbol, then $c \le s$. Moreover, when $c=s$, then either the deck is **degenerate**, or $s=k^2+k+1$ for some integer $k$, each card has $k+1$ symbols, each symbol appears $k+1$ times, and any pair of symbols appear together on one card. In other words, the deck represents a finite projective plane.

The degenerate possibility is called a **near-pencil**, where the last card, $C_s$  has all but the last symbol $S_s$, and any other card $C_i$ has only two symbols, $S_i$ and $S_s$. (Not a very exciting spot-it deck.)

The theorem is often described in a form dual to the spot it game, where the cards form the starting set, and the symbols represent subsets of the cards.

For more, start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_inequality.

Comment: "In other words, the deck represents a finite projective plane" - True, but it's worth mentioning that it's not necessarily the standard projective plane construction over a finite field. Weird projective planes also exist!

Comment: Agreed. I found lots of nice discussions about how to construct a spot it deck modeling a projective plane over a finite field of prime order, (Zwei's answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240113/what-are-the-mathematical-computational-principles-behind-this-game/6240247#6240247). The thing I did not easily find online was a discussion as to what game assumptions necessarily led to the projective plane axioms. In particular, you do not need to start with the assumption of a constant number of symbols/card.

Comment: [This](https://ericmoorhouse.org/handouts/Incidence_Geometry.pdf) is a very thorough source on finite geometries.

Answer (score 0):

Proof of formula for c<=s+1:

If $1\le c\le s$ then each of the $c$ cards shares one symbol with each of the other $c-1$ cards. So each card has $s-c+1$ symbols that are not used on any other cards so far. Since $c\le s$, we have $s-c+1 > 0$. So we can create card $c+1$ by choosing one of these $s-c+1$ symbols from each of the $c$ previous cards, and we can be sure there will be no duplicates in these $c$ symbols. This gives us $c$ symbols on card $c+1$, and we need to add a further $s-c$ completely new symbols (note that $s-c\ge0$). So:
$$m(c+1,s) = m(c,s) + s - c$$
And we know that $m(1,s) = s$, so $m(2,s) = 2s - 1$ ; $m(3,s) = 3s -3$ ... and in general
$$m(c,s) = \sum_{k=0}^{c-1}(s-k) = cs - \frac{c(c-1)}{2}$$
for $1\le c\le s+1$. And, as special cases of this general formula:
$$m(s,s) = m(s+1,s) = \frac{s(s+1)}{2}$$

I still don't have a formula for $c>s+1$.

Answer (score 0):

The useful construction here is a $p\times p$ square lattice. Let's denote its nodes by the pair of $1..p$ indices, $(i,j)$. Our pool of symbols will consist of these pairs plus some other symbols.

We can use it for some estimates. For example, let's take $p$ sets of symbols of the form $\{(i,1),(i,2),\ldots,(i,p)\}$ (one such set for every $i$), and add to each of this set a new symbol, $r$. Now we have $p$ cards with $p+1$ symbols on each with the desired properties. Then take $p$ more sets of symbols of the form $\{(1,j),(2,j),\ldots,(p,j),r'\}$ with a new symbol, $r'$. So now we have $p^2+2$ symbols total and $2p$ cards with $p+1$ symbols on each, so $m(2p,p+1)\leqslant p^2+2$. If we add diagonal sets $\{(i+1\bmod p,1),(i+2\bmod p,2),\ldots,(i+p\bmod p,p),r''\}$, we obtain the estimate $m(3p,p+1)\leqslant p^2+3$. For odd $p$ only, we can also take antidiagonals and get $m(4p,p+1)\leqslant p^2+4$; and so on.

What JeanMarie says in the comment is that if $p$ is prime then we can draw straight lines through all $p+1$ inequivalent directions on our lattice including two orthogonal directions ($p$ lines in every set of lines corresponding to a particular direction), and each diagonal will cross every diagonal from any other set exactly once. Each set except $\{(1,j),(2,j),\ldots,(p,j),r'\}$ is given by $\{(i+k\bmod p,1),(i+2k\bmod p,2),\ldots,(i+pk\bmod p,p),r_k\}$ for a fixed $k\in[0;p)$. So we have $p+1$ sets (straight lines), each of which requires an additional symbol $r_k$ or $r'$ to form a card with $p+1$ symbols. Also, we can unite these additional symbols into one more card. So we have $p^2+(p+1)$ symbols and the same number, $p(p+1)+1$, of cards. For $p+1$ symbols per card, this is the optimal number of symbols: $m(p^2+p+1,p+1)=p^2+p+1$ for prime $p$. Thanks to JeanMarie again.

Also, one more trivial estimate: $\max(m(c-1,s),m(c,s-1))\leqslant m(c,s)\leqslant\min(m(c-1,s)+s,m(c,s-1)+c)$.